# Is it possible to save an audio file in a dataframe and then call upon it?

Tags: r, audio, tuner

I'm trying to have a data frame that is able to contain audio. Downloaded an mp3 given a link and then want to save that audio in a data frame or other form if possible.

```
library(tuneR)

# Website
verb_formen <- "https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/infinitiv/"
# List of Verbs
verb_list <- c("analysieren", "formen", "erstellen")
# Empty List for Audio
audio_list <- vector(length = length(verb_list))


# Getting Audio for Each
for (x in 1:length(audio_list)){
  verb_link <- paste(verb_formen,verb_list[x], ".mp3", sep = "")
  audio_list[x] <- download.file(verb_link, paste("audio_",verb_list[x],".mp3"),mode="wb")
}

data.frame(verb_list, audio_list)
```

Comment: Can you specify your problem, what didn't work?

Comment: @jay.sf The issue is simply trying to call upon the mp3 file. I should be able to call the data by play(audio_list[1]) but it returns an interger instead of the mp3. And when you view the data_frame you can see that, it shows only 0s instead of indicating any data behind it

Comment: You need a `<- tuneR::readMP3(`, prior to `tuneR::play(` as play is looking for ,wav and that hasn't happened yet. Depending on the .mp3 characteristics, the readMP3, may, or may not readily translate to .wav.